# How to get the 'number' of occurrence of a value in a column in another column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, find-occurrences

I need to get the exact 'number' of occurrence of a particular value in a column in another column in dataframe.
To make it simpler, need the cumulative count of a repetitive value in a column

Consider the following example:

| col_A | col_B |
| --- | --- |
| test1 | some1 |
| test2 | some2 |
| test2 | some3 |
| test2 | some4 |
| test3 | some5 |
| test1 | some6 |
| test3 | some7 |

I need a col_C that gets the exact occurence number of col_A values
Consider the following:

| col_A | col_B | **col_C** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| test1 | some1 | 1 |
| test2 | some2 | 1 |
| test2 | some3 | 2 |
| test2 | some4 | 3 |
| test3 | some5 | 1 |
| test1 | some6 | 2 |
| test3 | some7 | 2 |

In row1 - 'test1' appears for the 1st time, so we got '1' in col_C; in row2 - 'test2' appears for the 1st time, so we got '1' in col_C; in row3 - 'test2' appears for the 2nd time, so we got '2' in col_C and so on

Did use value_counts, but am only getting the count of col_A values in col_C. I need the exact occurrence.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is cumcount() from groupby. It counts the amount of the same values in each column starting from 0. 
This code should work.

```
s = df.groupby('col_A').cumcount()
df['col_C'] =  s+1
```